# Cannot get URL from getDownloadURL from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to store my image to it , image is upload to the storage easily ,but when i try to get the url of the image form promise, it returns no url.

```
  const imageSaveHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        return storage
          .ref(`images/${image.name}`)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {console.log(url)})
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain more about what you mean by "it returns nothing".  How exactly are you observing this?

Comment: by nothing i mean it doesn't return a url to me when i console.log(url) in the promise

Comment: So, what exactly does it do, if not what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the handler you currently have as the third argument to `uploadTask.on` should be the fourth argument instead, according to this example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files:

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
  // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
      console.log('Upload is paused');
      break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
      console.log('Upload is running');
      break;
  }
}, function(error) {
  // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}, function() {
  // Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
});
```

Comment: i dont have issue with file upload , i copied the exact code from youtube tutorial but it worked for the guy in tutorial when he used console.log(url) he got the url

Comment: Respectfully, I would recommend trying to understand the code you're writing, rather than copy pasting code from a tutorial about an api that may have changed since the tutorial was posted.

Comment: thank you very much i solved it after reading the proper doc , sorry as i'm just in first year of college ,hence im not much aware of development world